# Is there a way to save my bufferedImage with the extention selected in my JfileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, save, bufferedimage, jfilechooser

i got a problem with my code. First of all, i created a JfileChooser, to save my bufferedImage into a file.
The problem is when i save it, if i don't write the extension in the window it will be a normal file instead of a jpg/png or other.. How can i do that?

I tryed some weird code like getting the description of fileextension but it doesn't work

```
    JFileChooser savechooser = new JFileChooser();
    savechooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG File", "jpg"));
    savechooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("PNG File", "png"));
    savechooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("GIF File", "gif"));
    int returnVal = savechooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        ImageIO.write(bImage, "png" , new File(savechooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()));
```

I expect a "test.png" or "test.jpeg", but the actual output would be a "test" file..

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to `ImageIO.write(...)` ("png" in your code) is the *format* of the file. This is not directly related to the *name* of the file. A *"file extension"* or suffix is simply part of the name of a file, and may be anything, although by convention it is used to indicate the format of the file (ie. nothing stops you from naming a JPEG file "foo.gif" if you really want to, and it is still a JPEG file). Windows typically uses this convention to determine file type and select the appropriate application to open the file though, so using a non-standard extension may be confusing.

To fix the the problem you see, it's probably best to make sure that filename ends with the correct extension, unless the user added one. For example (assumes the user chose PNG format, but you can easily adapt it to other formats as well):

```
// JFileChooser code as is

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   File file = savechooser.getSelectedFile();

   String fileName = file.getName();
   if (!fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) {
       file = new File(file.getParent(), fileName + ".png");
   }

   if (!ImageIO.write(image, "PNG" , file)) {
       // TODO: Handle file could not be written case
   }
}
```

The above will make sure the file has the correct file extension, unless the user supplied it himself.

I also see another problem in your code. You invoke `savechooser.setFileFilter(..)` three times. Each invocation will replace the current filter with the new one. You probably want to use `savechooser.addChoosableFileFilter(...)` instead (and perhaps `setFileFilter(..)` for the one you want to use as default). The filter will filter the files shown in the dialog, and thus what files the user clicks on, but does not impact the name the user supplied himself. You can get the current filter from `savechooser.getFileFilter()`, and use that to determine the format to use.

Here's a more complete solution:

```
JFileChooser savechooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter pngFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PNG File", "png")
savechooser.addChoosableFileFilter(pngFilter);
savechooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG File", "jpg"));
savechooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("GIF File", "gif"));

savechooser.setFileFilter(pngFilter); // Default choose PNG

int returnVal = savechooser.showSaveDialog(null);

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   File file = savechooser.getSelectedFile();

   FileNameExtensionFilter currentFilter = (FileNameExtensionFilter) savechooser.getFileFilter();
   String ext = currentFilter.getExtensions()[0];

   if (!currentFilter.accept(file)) {
       // File does not not have the correct extension, fix it
       String fileName = file.getName();
       file = new File(file.getParent(), fileName + "." + ext);
   }

   String format = "jpg".equals(ext) ? "JPEG" : ext; // May not be strictly necessary, just a reminder that file ext != file format

   if (!ImageIO.write(image, format , file)) {
       // TODO: Handle file could not be written case
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank for the Anwser, just to know, where did you save the Buffered Image bImage? And for the Handle of the not be written case,should i do a try catch method or use something else?

Comment: @Cronologium I just named the variable image. It’s the same as your bImage. Handle the not written case as you find appropriate. In a UI application, I would probably display a dialog explaining what happened to the user.